# c# visual studio!! como faço para o meu formulário ocupar a tela inteira? ele esta ficando só na metade da tela!

Tags: c#

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a imagem do meu formulário se vocês repararem ele não esta ocupando a tela inteira. eu gostaria de saber como fazer para ocupa a tela inteira.

Comment: É wpf? Se for passa o XAML desse formulário.

Answer (score 2):

Se for WPF, em XAML bastaria usar o seguinte:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Se for WinForms, basta alterar a opção `Dock` para `Fill`:

```
tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Ou alterar a propriedade diretamente no painel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estava escrevendo a resposta quando a sua apareceu! Isso vai resolver o problema